# Java Swing JFileChooser filter does not work for sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite, swing, jfilechooser

I  copied and modified an example from [here](https://mkyong.com/swing/java-swing-jfilechooser-example/). I changed it for sqlite. I am looking at a directory with .app, .jar, and .sqlite files. The .jar files are grayed out, but .sqlite and .app files are selectable. Why is the filter not making the .app files not selectable? I only want .sqlite to be selectable. I am running this on Mac OS X.

```
package org.todivefor.filechooser4;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

public class FileChooser4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
        jfc.setDialogTitle("Select DB");
        jfc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("SQLite DB", "sqlite");
        jfc.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);

        int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            System.out.println(jfc.getSelectedFile().getPath());
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

First, I don't think I understood how this was to work. I thought by specifying a filter with sqlite, I would not see anything without an .sqlite extension. In my testing, I find I can see files of all extensions, but can only select those with .sqlite. I tried my code above on both Mac OS X and Windows and saw different results. On Windows, I saw both .app and .sqlite files, but I could only select .sqlite files. On Mac OS X, I saw both .app and .sqlite files and could select either. I am not sure why this is, but has something to do with look and feel. On both Windows and Mac, I do not specify a look and feel, so I guess I get the default. On Windows, the .app files appear as folders. Whereas on Mac, they appear as files (still don't know why they are selectable). The application where I am using this, I control the L&F, and It works the way I expect, except for the Mac OS X L&F where I can select a .app extension file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows and the code you posted seem to be working. It may be a bug with Java. Is your Java up to date?

[image]

Comment: I posted this as answer because comments can't contain images.

Comment: My java is up-to-date. Can you select one of the .jar files?

Comment: You can upload an image to some Web site and add a link to it in your comment. That's one way to post a comment that contains an image.

Comment: @PeterReam I can't because they don't show up. The filter works correctly on my end.

Comment: *"I posted this as [an] answer because comments can't contain images."* No, but they can link to them. I regularly go to 'add an image' as though I'm about to make an answer, only to copy/paste the image link into a comment (then abandon the answer).